# Transferring the output from shell script to a variable

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I have written a script so that i can read from an oracle database and display it once i run the script. Is there any way that I can transfer the result to a variable ( Eg:output ) so that I can use if for some other calculations?

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect useid/password@CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='EF';
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current command prints the output in the console window, you should be able to do:

```
VARIABLE="$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect useid/password@CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='EF';
exit
EOF)"
```

And print out your variable:

```
echo "${VARIABLE}"
```

Comment: hey i got the answer by doing the same thing u did but removing the "

Answer (score 0):

this will also work:

```
var=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect useid/password@CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='EF';
exit;
EOF) 
echo $var
```